# How can I restore a file from the trash back to its original folder?

Tags: macos, trash

If I deleted files on my computer and they went to the trash, how can I send them back to the same folder that they came from?

On Windows, I can right-click the files and press restore.

Copying them to a location manually (e.g. via finder) is not a valid solution, since I don't know where they came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just right-click the file and select "Put Back"

[image]

Comment: I don't see that option. I'm on a standard user account (i.e. not administrator, if that makes any difference).

Comment: philip do you use pathfinder or something else?

Comment: @Am1 I just go to the Trash icon in the dock. @Senseful I am on Snow Leopard (10.6.6) I think it is a Snow Leopard only feature.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right.

Comment: @Senseful I started doing some digging in the Trash, .DS_Store seems to retain information about recent files' previous locations  (You will have to go in hex, I used Vim's  `%!xxd` ), I am not sure how else to do it right now , when I reach home I will have to try on a older mac (Pre Snow-Leopard)

Comment: @Philippe: I'm on 10.6.6 too, which is odd

Comment: Alright, I found out the problem, the file was deleted by a 3rd party app, so it doesn't have the Put Back option for some reason. If I delete a file from Finder, it does have the put back option.

Comment: @Senseful yes I realized the missing option when creating a file and manually moving it `mv file ~/.Trash/` maybe the third party apps are doing the same thing ?

Comment: @Philippe: That could likely be the problem, thanks for the help!