# How to determine original location of file that is currently in the Trash?

Tags: macos, finder, leopard, trash

Suppose some file "Any File.pdf" is in the Trash (aka `~/.Trash`).

How can I determine its original location?

By "original location" I mean the folder where that file would be moved to *if* one were to apply the "Put Back" command to it (but *without* actually doing so)?  (See figure below.)

(I had hoped that this information would be available through running "Get Info" on the file, but I did not find it there.)

[image: Put Back]

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/7123/14994) (last comment) this information seems to be stored in the .DS_Store file in the trash-folder

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/59376/how-to-tell-where-an-item-in-the-trash-came-from

Comment: See soultion here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5767821?tstart=0 **but it doesn't work if the enclosing folder has been deleted !**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data containing a file's original location before being placed in the Trash is keep in the **.DS_Store** file in the **~/.Trash** folder.

Since the trash folder is hidden it can not normally be found using the finder application.  The easiest way to find this file is by using the Terminal and entering the following commands.

```
$cd ~/.Trash
$open -e .DS_Store
```

This will open the file in TextEdit.  From there you should be able to quickly search for the file by its name and its original path.

Its seems that files in .DS_Store follow the pattern of:

```
FILE_NAME ptbLustr ORIGINAL_PATH_TO_FILE
```

Note spaces are added just for readability.

Comment: Did you actually test that? .DS_Store contains a lot of binary data, I didn't find any file names at all.

Comment: I did test this on my own machine before posting.  I found references to files in my Trash and their original locations.

Comment: Ah, seems to depend on the language settings, it's all Unicode here.

Comment: I believe this answer only works for OS X around/before 10.4 or 10.5 as .DS_Store is [now a binary file and undocumented by Apple](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DS_Store_File_Format).

Comment: It does still work here in OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: still works on OSX 10.11.5. It works when I open it in TextEdit, but not Sublime Text

Comment: It is a binary file, but you can still see the strings that are stored in it, in most text editors. However, the search doesn't seem to work correctly on it when opened in TextEdit. I can see all my files there, but when I try to search for more than a single character at a time, it returns 0 results (even though if I search for those characters one at a time, it finds them all). This probably depends on the editor it's opened in, but TextWrangler is the same way. Unfortunately, without the search working, this method is pretty difficult to use.

Comment: @David, Surely you're going to say waht ptbLustr means?

Comment: @Elezar, Yes that's the definition of a binary file. There are readable text strings in loads of binary files. If its not completely unicode readable its binary.

Comment: @Pacerier Yeah, but it seems pretty clear from other comments that not everyone is aware of that fact, so I was pointing it out.

Comment: When I try these directions on macOS Catalina, I get the error 'The document ".DS_Store" could not be opened. You don't have permission.'

Comment: If you get the "You don't have permission" error, ensure that [Terminal has access to the file system](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/).

Answer (score 1):

The information about the original location is stored within *DS_Store* file. In older version of *OS X* it was stored in plain text, and now in binary format. These formats aren't documented by Apple, however, there is a tool created by [*Wim L*](https://github.com/wiml) which can read it.

The tool is written in Perl, `Mac::Finder::DSStore` project provides routines for reading and writing the `.DS_Store` files generated by the macOS.

As per initial commit, the above tool is based on Mark Mitrovai's work plus author own investigation.

Using `examples/dsstore_dump.pl` would attempt to dump a store file's records in a more human-readable format.

Example usage:

```
$ perl dsstore_dump.pl ~/.Trash/.DS_Store

    &makeEntries("foo.png",
        ptbL => "Users/username/Desktop/",
        ptbN => "foo.png"
    ),
```

<sup>See: [dsstore repo at hhhh.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20170602034746/http://www.hhhh.org:80/src/hg/dsstore) and [older repo at GitHub](https://github.com/dscho/dsstore).</sup>

Comment: The repo server hhhh.org is returning Internal Server Error. This answer assumes fairly advanced programming knowledge and implies a lot of steps. Step-by-step instructions would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great write up and some easier solutions posted at http://ponderthebits.com/2017/01/mac-dumpster-diving-identifying-deleted-file-references-in-the-trash-ds_store-files-part-1/

Including this Terminal one-liner to convert a `.DS_Store` file to (mostly) text:

```
xxd -p <path/to/.DS_Store> | sed 's/00//g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/0x\1 /g' | xxd -r -p | strings | sed 's/ptb[LN]ustr//g'
```

Comment: Rather than duplicating a [prior answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296563/37797), perhaps you could expand the command to specifically return the Put Back location, which would be more useful for this question individually?

Comment: I'm "duplicating" my own answer, which I posted on 3 relevant threads which provided no solution that worked for me. Just trying to save other people the hour of searching I had to do. Sorry if I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: I understand that and you've not doing anything wrong, just thought it might be useful to tailor this one to something more specific for the particular question. Also, by providing the link in my previous comment, the other question now shows in the linked questions list on the right which might be useful to others.

Comment: result is hardly satisfactory.

Answer (score -3):

'Put Back' the File, Use the search function to search for the file, When you find your file, Right-Click it and select "Open Enclosing Folder"

Comment: What if the same file name appears more than once on the file system? This approach will fail for that case. Better to read the meta data OS X is reading to determine the 'Put Back' location in the first place.

Comment: @IanC., But this hazytruth option seemsto be the only option now that dsstore is binary

Comment: Fuzzytruth i mean...

Comment: 