# Examine a .DS_Store file?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

My understanding of a .DS_Store file is that is contains details that describe a folder and the files within that folder. Based on that description, I can think of a few uses from being able to read a .DS_Store file.

My question: Is there any form of a tool or program that would allow for the reading/examination of a .DS_Store file?

Follow up question: If there's not a tool, can anyone explain to me the syntax of the file?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) page? Especially the sentence "Its internal structure is proprietary"? And there are links to some pages with reverse-engineered format at the bottom of the article too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a great write up and some easier solutions posted at http://ponderthebits.com/2017/01/mac-dumpster-diving-identifying-deleted-file-references-in-the-trash-ds_store-files-part-1/

Including this Terminal one-liner to convert a `.DS_Store` file to (mostly) text:

```
xxd -p <path/to/.DS_Store> | sed 's/00//g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/0x\1 /g' | xxd -r -p | strings | sed 's/ptb[LN]ustr//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hexdump` or `xxd` to inspect the file contents directly - it is a binary file.

I would start with a perl or Python package rather than reinvent the wheel.

- http://search.cpan.org/~wiml/Mac-Finder-DSStore/DSStoreFormat.pod
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ds_store