# How do I check where the file in .Trash was removed from?

Tags: finder, trash, macos

I've some files appearing in Trash folder. How do I check from where they were removed?

I've Tried 'Get Info', but it doesn't tell me from where it was removed. The only option I've is 'Put Back', but again, to where?

How do I check this on OS X 10.9?

Comment: There is a great write up and some easier solutions posted at http://ponderthebits.com/2017/01/mac-dumpster-diving-identifying-deleted-file-references-in-the-trash-ds_store-files-part-1/ including this Terminal one-liner to convert a `.DS_Store` file to (mostly) text: `xxd -p <path/to/.DS_Store> | sed 's/00//g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/0x\1 /g' | xxd -r -p | strings | sed 's/ptb[LN]ustr//g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [previous information](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52357/22781), the information about original location is stored within *DS_Store* file. In older version of OS X it was just a plain text and now binary format and it's undocumented by Apple, however there is a tool created by [Wim L](https://github.com/wiml) which can reads it.

Written in perl `Mac::Finder::DSStore` project provides routines for reading and writing the `.DS_Store` files generated by the OS X.

Using `examples/dsstore_dump.pl` would attempt to dump a store file's records in a more human-readable format.

Example usage:

```
$ perl dsstore_dump.pl ~/.Trash/.DS_Store

    &makeEntries("foo.png",
        ptbL => "Users/username/Desktop/",
        ptbN => "foo.png"
    ),
```

See: [dsstore repo at hhhh.org](http://www.hhhh.org/src/hg/dsstore/) and [older repo at GitHub](https://github.com/dscho/dsstore)

Comment: So if its undocumented how does he do it?

Comment: @Pacerier By reverse engineering I guess. As per this [commit message](http://www.hhhh.org/src/hg/dsstore/rev/ac140fe6aaa8) , it's 'based on Mark Mitrovai's work plus own investigation'.

Answer (score 4):

You can isolate things a little if you don't mind using terminal.

The trash in finder is an overlay of trash from each mounted volume and each user. Furthermore, you can see the filename of the file and search using spotlight to see if there are similar files or use spotlight to search in Time Machine to find where the file was before it was trashed.

The pragmatic way to solve this is to drag the file to your desktop and then open/inspect/file it accordingly. (Or to just let [Finder put it back](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/how-can-i-restore-a-file-from-the-trash-back-to-its-original-folder) and then use spotlight to find it).

To use terminal:

```
ls -la ~/.Trash
sudo ls -la /.Trashes
```

If you're not familiar with sudo and that it can delete anything with no recovery, I'd recommend not using sudo and asking follow on questions to learn more about terminal.

Comment: You can no longer just open .DS_Store in a text editor (go ahead and try it if you want) since it's not a text file. The original path is still locked in that file, but there are easier ways to get  your eventual problem solved than waiting for some tool to decode that file.

Comment: Actually, you can open it, it's just encoded so you can't *understand* it.

Comment: @bmike, Is `sudo ls -la /.Trashes` a safe operation or will i lose data?

Comment: @Pacerier It's safe (`ls` = list directory).